# Continuity of $f(x)=\left\lfloor \frac12 x -1\right\rfloor$

Tags: continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> How can you define the domain of a floor function, i.e. in interval notation, for which it is continuous?
>   For example, for the following function:
>   $$f(x)=\left\lfloor \frac12 x -1\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Do you want to find the domain, or do you know it and really want to "define" it, by which I understand that you want to know how to write the domain down?

Comment: Hint: when is $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor $ discontinuous?

Comment: The basic floor function $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor$ is continuous everywhere except when $x$ is an integer. But now it's $\frac12x-1$ that must be fractional (= non-integer). For interval notation, note that the intervals of fractional numbers take the form $(n,n+1)$ for integers $n$, so put $\frac12x-1\in(n,n+1)$ and simplify. (This may look more familiar if you write it as a compound inequality along the way.)

Comment: What do you mean by _the_ domain for which it is continuous?  There are many different domains on which it is continuous.

Comment: <s>@EricWofsey :  There is a unique maximal domain on which it is continuous, which (in this case) is simply the set of all points at which it is continuous if you provisionally take the domain to be the entire real line.  So that's probably the desired answer.</s> (Not actually true, sorry; example, $[2,4)$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** look for intervals of the form $(2n+2,2n+4)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's only right-continuous at $2n+2$; the relevant intervals are of the form $(2n+2,2n+4)$.

Comment: @TobyBartels You are correct. I have fixed the error. Thanks.

Comment: could it be [2n, 2n+2) (since it is right continuous at 2n), for example [0,2), [2,4) etc.?

Comment: @GreatQuestion Assuming that you want the **maximal** set on which this function is continuous, then at all boundary points you will need to check for both left and right continuity. In that case, the function is NOT continuous at end points of the said intervals.

Comment: @AnuragA right, but why do you choose (2n+2,2n+4) instead of just (2n,2n+2)? Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: I presume because $(2n+2,2n+4)$ is what you naturally get by setting $\frac12x-1\in(n,n+1)$. Of course, once you have that, you can simplify by shifting the meaning of $n$. As for $[2n,2n+2)$, the function is certainly continuous if restricted to that interval, but then you can't combine them.  To be more specific, you can restrict it to $[0,2)$ or to $[2,4)$, but you can't restrict it to $[0,2)\cup[2,4)$. If you stick to open intervals, however, then you can join them all up: the function is continuous on $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(2n,2n+2)$.